# Next JS - Esta página se llama a si mismo una y otra vez

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Tengo un componente que se llama **marca** en **Next.js**, la idea es que cada vez que cargue una página distinta como puede ser.

http://localhost:3000/marca/vw o bien http://localhost:3000/marca/ford

Muestra un listado de `N` items, cogiendo como valor el parámetro de la URI siendo `vw` o `ford` el campo marca, para ello tengo este código:

El archivo se llama marca y esta dentro de **pages/marca/[marca]**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import GuestLayout from '@/components/Layouts/GuestLayout'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Marca = () => {
    const [coches, setCoches] = useState([])
    const router = useRouter()
    const marca = router.query.marcas
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:8000/api/coches/marcas/${marca}`,
            )
            const data = await response.json()
            setCoches(data)
        }

        fetchData()
    })


    return (
        <GuestLayout marca={marca}>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4">
                {coches.map(coche => (
                    <Link href={`/cars/${coche.id}`} key={coche.id} passHref>
                        <div className="border p-4 flex md:flex-row flex-col">
                            <div className="w-full">
                                <p className="mb-2">
                                    Marca : {coche.marca.toUpperCase()}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    )
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </GuestLayout>
    )
}

export default Marca
```

El problema que tengo con este código que no para de recargarse, solo hace una vez la llamada a la API pero muestra elementos y después desaparecen si en el `useEffect` le pongo la dependencia bien a [router] o [marca] quedando de esta forma.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:8000/api/coches/marcas/${marca}`,
        )
        const data = await response.json()
        setCoches(data)
    }

    fetchData()
} , [router,marca])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una llamada a una API debe hacerse en momentos precisos. Si vos no pones ninguna dependencia, eso se va a ejecutar cada vez que haya un cambio en el componente. Y como esa llamada setea un estado, el componente cambia, entonces el render se vuelve infinito.

Creo que deberias hacer la llamada solo al montarse el componente (dependencia vacia `[]`), y en el momento que haces el map para renderizar, asegurarte antes que los datos esten cargados:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import GuestLayout from '@/components/Layouts/GuestLayout'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Marca = () => {
    const [coches, setCoches] = useState([])
    const router = useRouter()
    const marca = router.query.marcas
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:8000/api/coches/marcas/${marca}`,
            )
            const data = await response.json()
            setCoches(data)
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])


    return (
        <GuestLayout marca={marca}>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4">
                {coches && coches.length > 0 && coches.map(coche => {
                    return(
                      <Link href={`/cars/${coche.id}`} key={coche.id} passHref>
                        <div className="border p-4 flex md:flex-row flex-col">
                            <div className="w-full">
                                <p className="mb-2">
                                    Marca : {coche.marca.toUpperCase()}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </Link>
                     )
                   })
                }
            </div>
        </GuestLayout>
    )
}

export default Marca
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora lo ví